# Will NORAD Santa tracker be affected by the government shutdown?

Tags: united-states, congress, government-shutdown

If the government shutdown that started about 12 hours ago (at the moment of writing the question) will continue (and probably will) later than 24 december, than what will happen with NORAD Santa tracker?

[This article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/21/us/politics/what-happens-government-shutdown.html?action=click&module=Spotlight&pgtype=Homepage) says it will not affect the military, but still, leaving the joke aside, it is a government shutdown and NORAD Santa would seem as using some money for really nothing especially now.

Comment: More important question: how will counter-value present strikes be affected?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The NORAD Santa tracker will operate as normal, according to the NORAD official twitter webpage (@Norad_Northcom)

> In the event of a government shutdown, NORAD will continue with its
> 63-year tradition of NORAD Tracks Santa on Dec. 24. Military personnel
> who conduct NORAD Tracks Santa are supported by approximately 1,500
> volunteers who make the program possible each and every year.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter:](https://twitter.com/Norad_Northcom/status/1076184061784264705)</sup></sub>

---

On a related note, I can also confirm that since Santa isn't an employee of the US government, his deliveries will be unaffected.

Comment: Wow...as usual, the military seems to be the most advantaged of all the departments. And I don't doubt that this all tracking thing is worth some good millions

Comment: @user17 - I suspect that the NORAD tracker uses very little of NORAD's actual resources. Per the [FAQ](http://noradsanta.wikia.com/wiki/About_Santa_-_FAQs); "***How much money is spent on this project?**
The NORAD Tracks Santa program is made possible by volunteers and through the support of corporate partners who bear virtually all of the costs.*"

Comment: "Santa isn't an employee of the US government" - *\[citation needed]*

Comment: @user4012 - I've heard that the best part of working for Santa is the excellent elf insurance

Comment: @user4012 I've heard rumors that SANTA is the codename of a US intelligence asset with a "present delivery" cover story.

Comment: @user17 Incidentally, the Army, Navy, Air Force, and Marines aren't affected by the shutdown because the Defense Department is one of the departments whose full FY2019 funding was passed in September. The Coast Guard is affected because they're under DHS, but as active military they're still expected to work.